# Add existing constraint to a new table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, constraints

I am trying to create a foreign key in a new table and that key from the source table already has pre-existing constraint so do i have to redo the constraint on the new table or it will automatically follow that constraint condition?
If I have to redo what would a typical SQL statement be?

Comment: No need to redo the constraint

Comment: Tks! Please respond as answer so I can mark u as right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do redo the constraint while referencing a foreign key which already has a constraint